# Sharepoint 2013 search results webpart : Show only exact match

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, ootb

I am trying to use OOTB Search results webpart and trying to configure it such that whenever user types in any keyword, the search should only return results where that full keyword is exactly matched(only the text ,not the case). Right now by default SharePoint returns results where a part of it is matched.